# How to pass value as attribute in angularJs custom directive

Tags: angularjs, attributes, directive

I am trying to pass some value as attribute in custom directive and access inside template, but value is coming as blank.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  // $scope.temp = "temp123";

});

app.directive("dirName" , function(){


  return {
    template: "<div> temp = {{temp}} </div>",
    temp:'@',

  };



});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.4.6"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <dir-name temp="my value"></dir-name>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the plunker link :
http://plnkr.co/edit/r95YGxS19cMvWMWZMPcN

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

you need to define the `scope` of the directive then, `temp` will be a variable within the directive scope.

```
return {
    template: "<div> temp = {{temp}} </div>",
    scope: {
      temp:'@'
    }   
};
```

updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/X5QM7ytLIEHOXW882gXH?p=preview)

if you need to bind the `MainCtrl` value to directive then use `=` instead of `@` as in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/euBSA49ZBnPYmcjBsWen?p=preview)

and there is another one (`&`) to point to a function within `MainCtrl`. check this [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: glad to help you & don't forget to go though the doc :) cherrz